# Generate Sublist from List

Tags: python

I wanna split a list into a list of sublists. E.g.

```
amino = ['Met','Phe','Pro','Ala','Ser','Met','Ser','Gly','Gly','Met','Thr','Trp']
```

should result in

```
amino_split = [['Met','Phe','Pro','Ala','Ser'],['Met','Ser','Gly','Gly'],['Met','Thr','Trp']]
```

My first thought was to get all indices of `'Met'` and build range-like tuples `[(0, 4), (5, 8), (9, 11)]` and then slice the list. But that seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut..

Comment: Where did `'Val'` and `'Cys'` come from in the second sublist?

Comment: you're absolute right, I shortened the list for better visibility and missed out shortening `amino_split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```
w = []
[w.append([]) or w[-1].append(e) if 'Met' in e else w[-1].append(e) for e in amino]
```

Output (in `w`):

```
[['Met', 'Phe', 'Pro', 'Ala', 'Ser'],
 ['Met', 'Ser', 'Gly', 'Gly'],
 ['Met', 'Thr', 'Trp']]
```

Comment: I like the pythonic way without importing modules! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
amino = ['Met','Phe','Pro','Ala','Ser','Met','Ser','Gly','Gly','Met','Thr','Trp']
final_vals = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(amino, key=lambda x:x == 'Met')]
last_data = [final_vals[i]+final_vals[i+1] for i in range(0, len(final_vals), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['Met', 'Phe', 'Pro', 'Ala', 'Ser'], ['Met', 'Ser', 'Gly', 'Gly'], ['Met', 'Thr', 'Trp']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one solution using reduce.

```
import functools
amino = ['Met','Phe','Pro','Ala','Ser','Met','Ser','Gly','Gly','Met','Thr','Trp']
print(functools.reduce(lambda pre, cur: pre.append([cur]) or pre if cur == 'Met' else pre[-1].append(cur) or pre, amino, []))
```

Output:

```
[['Met', 'Phe', 'Pro', 'Ala', 'Ser'], ['Met', 'Ser', 'Gly', 'Gly'], ['Met', 'Thr', 'Trp']]
[Finished in 0.204s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
amino = ['Met','Phe','Pro','Ala','Ser','Met','Ser','Gly','Gly','Met','Thr','Trp']
s = pd.Series(amino)
s.groupby(s.eq('Met').cumsum()).apply(list).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['Met', 'Phe', 'Pro', 'Ala', 'Ser'],
 ['Met', 'Ser', 'Gly', 'Gly'],
 ['Met', 'Thr', 'Trp']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If range is fixed then you can normally use splicing to achieve your goal.
ex; `[amino[:5],amino[5:9],amino[9:12]]`